# Is Israel official story of the issue were correct?

Tags: israel

https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/apr/01/israel-rejects-un-and-eu-calls-for-inquiry-into-gaza-bloodshed

The official story is that there is a violent riot. And that the snipper acts appropiately.

However, Israel refuses independent investigators to coroborate the stories.

How true is it?

Comment: Questions about motivations aren't on-topic here, they can't really be answered within our rules.

Comment: I didn't remember asking this in sceptics. I thought I ask this in political stackexchange. Did someone move it here?

Comment: No it was defo asked here and not migrated

Comment: It's a mistake then. Would someone please move it to political stackexchange.

Comment: You can simply reask the question on Politics, migration is overkill for unanswered questions.

Comment: I change the question to something more suitable for this site. Will ask again in politics.

Comment: While I agree this is off topic one article pretty much addresses  this: http://www.jpost.com/Arab-Israeli-Conflict/Report-80-percent-of-Palestinians-killed-in-Gaza-border-crisis-were-terrorists-549511  The highly selective targeting basically shows that it was somehow their behavior that got them killed as they don't fight in uniform--the IDF would have no other way to single out militants.

Comment: I think that's good enough as an answer. I mean one guy got shot by sniper in the leg. That is a reasonable outcome. I would shoot rubber bullet but then, I am not jewish.